# Move patch rather than remove it

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a graph that is gradually revealed. Since this should happen with a huge dataset and on several subplots simultaneously, I was planning to *move* the `patch` rather than remove it and draw it from scratch in order to accelerate the code.

My problem is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527930/matplotlib-update-position-of-patches-or-set-xy-for-circles). However, I could not resolve it.

Here is a *minimal* working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nmax = 10
xdata = range(nmax)
ydata = np.random.random(nmax)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o-')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(xdata)
plt.ion()

i = 0
while i <= nmax:
    # ------------ Here I would like to move it rather than remove and redraw.
    if i > 0:
        rect.remove()
    rect = plt.Rectangle((i, 0), nmax - i, 1, zorder = 10)
    ax.add_patch(rect)
    # ------------
    plt.pause(0.1)
    i += 1

plt.pause(3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this works for you.  Instead of removing the patch, you just update its position and its width (with `rect.set_x(left_x)` and `rect.set_width(width)`), and then redraw the canvas.  Try replacing your loop with this (note that the `Rectangle` is created *once*, before the loop):

```
rect = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), nmax, 1, zorder=10)
ax.add_patch(rect)

for i in range(nmax):
    rect.set_x(i)
    rect.set_width(nmax - i)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Better to use `draw_idle` to avoid excessive re-redraws.